# Ping spikes when pinging router

Tags: networking, router, ping, localhost, fritzbox

Is it normal to get some spikes while pinging the router?

Normally I get some spikes of max 15ms and I am using a wired connection, this doesn't seems to be right.

My interface is a gigabit, my cable is cat 6e and my router it is a FRITZ!Box 7530.

```
Ping statistics for 192.168.178.1:
    Packets: Sent = 54, Received = 54, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 15ms, Average = 0ms
Control-C
```

Does this seems to be an issue with the router itself or any other problem like, windows or cable?

[Router Page](https://boxmatrix.info/wiki/FRITZ!Box_7530)

Best.

Comment: 15ms is high. Typically you'd see 1-2ms, maybe 4ms now and then. What the cause is however, i cant tell you. Try another cable if possible.

Comment: First ping takes longer due to arp request. After that, who knows... You would need to look at the RTT of every packet and the loading on the network, host & target when it spikes. But really, it does not matter as these packets are given low priority. If you look at the results, the average is the same as the minimum suggesting it was only a single packet that spiked hinting that it was due to arp.

Comment: I was getting several high spikes until I disable the wifi for the main router, then I started to see those 15ms spikes not so often. I will try to get a new pair of cables and I will try to mitigate with wireshark if it is a problem with my computer. I am suspecting it could be router which only has 256mb ram and this is generating some spikes.

Comment: Nothing to do with RAM unless it is SEVERELY limited which is unlikely. Typically the os will take the packet, swap src & destination addresses and send it back out the interface it came in. If it is due to RAM, then you would see major problems with your lan.

Comment: Did you find what was causing this? I have the exact same issue over ethernet directly from my Windows 10 machine to the router (1.5m cable). The ping spikes to 15ms once every few seconds or minutes. I've tried messing around with drivers & advanced settings, nothing. (I also tested this on a raspberry Pi, pinging to the router via ethernet and I don't get those spikes).